# Breaking after one of several string replaces occur

Tags: javascript, strings, regex

I have a script that matches a string against ~20 different regexs for the purpose of changing it. They are ordered and formed that the string will only ever match against one. How can I avoid checking all the `str.replace`s after I match once?

My code here works, but I repeat myself a lot and it does not seem optimal.

The `while` loop exists so I could break, I don't actually need to loop through anything - and in fact I ensure I don't loop at the end of it. I'm merely looking for a way to *stop* performing replaces, when I know they will do nothing.

```
function format_number(input){
    var str = input.value;
    str.toString();
    var copy = str;
    var checked = false;
    while (!checked) {
        str = str.replace(/regex1/, 'replace1');
        if (copy != str) {break;}
        str = str.replace(/regex2/, 'replace2'); 
        if (copy != str) {break;}
        str = str.replace(/regex3/, 'replace3');
        if (copy != str) {break;}
        str = str.replace(/regex4/, 'replace4');
        if (copy != str) {break;}
        str = str.replace(/regex5/, 'replace5');
        if (copy != str) {break;}
        str = str.replace(/regex6/, 'replace6');
        if (copy != str) {break;}
        str = str.replace(/regex7/, 'replace7');
        if (copy != str) {break;}
        str = str.replace(/regex8/, 'replace8');
        if (copy != str) {break;}
        str = str.replace(/regex9/, 'replace9');
        if (copy != str) {break;}
        str = str.replace(/regex10/, 'replace10');
        if (copy != str) {break;}
        str = str.replace(/regex11/, 'replace11');
        if (copy != str) {break;}
        str = str.replace(/regex12/, 'replace12');
        if (copy != str) {break;}
        str = str.replace(/regex13/, 'replace13');
        if (copy != str) {break;}
        str = str.replace(/regex14/, 'replace14');
        if (copy != str) {break;}
        str = str.replace(/regex15/, 'replace15');
        if (copy != str) {break;}
        str = str.replace(/regex16/, 'replace16');
        if (copy != str) {break;}
        str = str.replace(/regex17/, 'replace17');
        if (copy != str) {break;}
        checked = true;
    }
    input.value=str;
}
```

Comment: When is `checked` set to `true`? Why is this an infinite loop at all?

Comment: My mistake, I added the final line manually and put it in incorrectly. It should break after the first iteration.

Comment: Then what good is that loop at all?

Comment: It lets me use 'break' to avoid unnecessarily running through the other regexs.

Comment: Hm, a labelled block would've done that as well… or using if-else-statements. Regardless, what is the goal of this code? To have `checked` be `true` or `false`? To modify `str`?

Comment: I have a feeling that this code could be improved much more if only we could also see the actual regexes. It's hard for me to understand what kind secret proprietary replacements one could do inside a function called `format_number`. Or maybe the function doesn't do what it's name suggests.

Comment: @ReneSaarsoo Haha I probably don't *need* to hide the regex, but it belongs to the company I work for for internal tracking. Pretty much I'm manipulating a UPC to match a standardized form, and the UPC can come in many different forms. The first regex is just to shorten any number to 13 digits -  
 `str = str.replace(/^([0-9]{13})[0-9]+$/, '$1');`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This seems to be a fine case for a loop over the expressions:

```
function format_input(input) {
    // decouple DOM things from pure functionality!
    input.value = format_number(input.value);
}
function format_number(str) {
    var replacements = [
        [/regex1/, 'replace1'],
        [/regex2/, 'replace2'],
        [/regex3/, 'replace3'],
        [/regex4/, 'replace4'],
        [/regex5/, 'replace5'],
        [/regex6/, 'replace6'],
        [/regex7/, 'replace7'],
        [/regex8/, 'replace8'],
        [/regex9/, 'replace9'],
        [/regex10/, 'replace10'],
        [/regex11/, 'replace11'],
        [/regex12/, 'replace12'],
        [/regex13/, 'replace13'],
        [/regex14/, 'replace14'],
        [/regex15/, 'replace15'],
        [/regex16/, 'replace16'],
        [/regex17/, 'replace17']
    ];
    for (var i=0; i<replacements.length; i++) {
        var copy = str.replace(replacements[i][0], replacements[i][1]);
        if (str != copy)
            return copy;
    }
    return str;
}
```